# Star questions as favorite through keyboard operation

Tags: support, feature-request, bookmarks, keyboard-shortcuts

I am now selecting 'star' by 'Tab' key. The problem is that if I pass over it, I cannot roll back to it by keyboard operation.

What's a better solution to star a question without using a mouse?

Comment: @JoeC what do you have against keyboards?  Not having to move my hands between devices makes me more productive and helps avoid RSI. Keyboard shortcuts really make a difference there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle forward through elements, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle *backwards* through elements, and hit <kbd>Return</kbd> to simulate a click of an element.  This will allow you to favorite a question without the use of the mouse.